# Question regarding algebraicity of two elements whose sum and product are algebraic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $\alpha , \beta \in \Bbb C$ and suppose $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$ are algebraic over $\Bbb Q$. Prove  $\alpha , \beta$ are algebraic over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking to prove that the roots of a quadratic polynomial with algebraic coefficients are themselves algebraic, which is well-known, and true for all polynomials, regardless of their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\alpha^2-(\alpha+\beta)\alpha + \alpha \beta = 0$. Hence, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta,\alpha\beta)$. But $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\beta,\alpha\beta)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you.